# How to get Get job_data field from db for spring quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

A very simple question, we have below configuration for Spring Quartz

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

The `qrtz_job_details` table has a blob field called `JOB_DATA`, which I am planning to use to pass job specific data into the job. but, I am not sure on how to access this filed from with in the job.